# laravel 4 close database connection

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm new in laravel. I just create application using this framework. My application is web scraping, so it can take a minute to complete a request. The problem is each request executed one after another. I think this is because the database connection still open until the request finished. So how to close the database connection?

Comment: Maybe you should re-think your entire concept. When a request takes a minute to complete a request you should put those jobs in a [Queue](http://four.laravel.com/docs/queue).

Comment: I'm confusing with the Queue. Maybe I will use later. Right now I just want to disconnect the current db connection so other request can executed without waiting to current request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I just debugging my code and got that the problem is in session driver. I change session driver from native to cookie and the request not waiting other request anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late but you can do:

```
DB::disconnect('DataBase');
```

Comment: Downvote as when I call this I get an exception: Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection' does not have a method 'disconnect' in /path/to/Illuminate/Database/Capsule/Manager.php on line 280